# Regularity of semilinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I'm reading Evans' PDE book (second edition) and I tried to solve this problem but I'm a little confused

Problem 7, chapter 6:

Let $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ have compact support and be a weak solution of the semilinear PDE 
\begin{equation}
    -\Delta u+c(u)=f \text{  in  } \mathbb{R}^n
\end{equation}
where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $c:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth, with $c(0)=0$ and $c'\geq 0$. Prove $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Evans gives a hint to mimic the theorem 6.3.1 without the cutoff function.  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:
$-\Delta u = f - c(u)$.

Now you are done if you can show that the RHS is in $L^2$ by elliptic regularity.
To do this it is of course enough to show that $c(u)$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. $$\int |c(u)|^2 = \int_{\text{supp}(u)}|c(u)|^2 \le \|c\|^2_{L^{\infty}(\text{supp}(u))}|\text{supp}(u)| < \infty$$

Do you think this work? Let me know! :)

Comment: it won't for $u=loglog(1-1/|x|)$ and $c=e^{e^{x}}-e$

Comment: of course it does not work.. I am sorry but for some reason I was under the impression that $c$ had compact support. I must have dreamt this condition since it appears that the question has not been modified. Thank you for pointing it out! :)